# Alternative version of find_if which finds all, not just the first?

Tags: stl, iterator, c++

Is there an alternative version of `std::find_if` that returns an iterator over all found elements, instead of just the first one?

Example:

```
bool IsOdd (int i) {
  return ((i % 2) == 1);
}

std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);

std::vector<int>::iterator it = find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), IsOdd);
for(; it != v.end(); ++it) {
  std::cout << "odd: " << *it << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I used to remain silent but apparently (following a discussion) it bothers others too: please don't use the "functional-programming" tag just because there is a pointer to a function in your code. If anything, the c++ tags will help people who can answer find your question faster.

Comment: returning iterator to vector/list/whatever of all of the occurences, and then operating over it (maybe calling function at 'all' results) sounds like functional programming to me.

Comment: @Yossarian You'd better update the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming then. Currently it starts with "mathematical functions" (meaning pure) and "avoids state and mutable data" (I am not familiar with C++ iterators but they seem to me a good illustration of what "mutable" is).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just use a `for` loop:

```
for (std::vector<int>:iterator it = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), IsOdd);
     it != v.end();
     it = std::find_if(++it, v.end(), IsOdd))
{
    // ...
}
```

Alternatively, you can put your condition and action into a functor (performing the action only if the condition is true) and just use `std::foreach`.

Answer (score 1):

in STL there isn't, but boost offers this funcionality:

[boost::algorithm::find_all](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/algorithm/find_all.html)

Comment: The answer is outdated, the link is dead. The correct answer is [boost::filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html)

Answer (score 0):

First always try to come up with typical STL usage itself, you can go for boost as well. Here is more simplified form from the above mentioned answer by Charles.

```
    vec_loc = find_if(v3.begin(), v3.end(), isOdd);
if (vec_loc != v3.end())
{
    cout << "odd elem. found at " << (vec_loc - v3.begin()) << "and elem found is " << *vec_loc << endl;
    ++vec_loc;
}
for (;vec_loc != v3.end();vec_loc++) 
{
    vec_loc = find_if(vec_loc, v3.end(), isOdd);
    if (vec_loc == v3.end())
        break;
    cout << "odd elem. found at " << (vec_loc - v3.begin()) << "and elem found is " << *vec_loc << endl;
}
```