# return items from QList<MyObject> through text string

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I need to do finder in my mobile application. So I've this object:

```
class Category
{
    public:
    Category();

    QString title;
    QString description;

};
```

on application start i load from json url some objects and i put they in a QList list;

I've done one method that update a model when i click FIND on my gui.

```
    void CategoryModel::searchByTextInCategoryList(QString testo)
    {
        QList<Category> lista = singleton::instance().categoryCompleteList;
        auto itObj = std::find_if(lista.begin(), lista.end(), [](Category o) { return o.title == "my searched text"; }); 
        //this not for me
    }
```

**I need a similar solutiion, if possible:**

```
QList<Category> result = lista.find_all.where(lista.at(index).title == "search text");
```

exist this possibility ?

This method don't work really fine for me, because I need to get all objects that contains the same word.
Could help me ? 
I'm came from C#, and in C# I used Linq, there is similar linq in QT to search in Qlist by text ?

In few words...i need to do a query in QList and return multiple items from list.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344673/alternative-version-of-find-if-which-finds-all-not-just-the-first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternative version of find\_if which finds all, not just the first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344673/alternative-version-of-find-if-which-finds-all-not-just-the-first)

Comment: How to works find by text in your example sorry ??

Comment: Yoa already have written your comparator.

Comment: I needn't a comparatore, I need to search by text and returns elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a good old foreach ?

```
void CategoryModel::searchByTextInCategoryList(QString testo)
{
    QList<Category> lista = singleton::instance().categoryCompleteList;
    QList<Category> results;
    foreach(Category c, lista) { 
        if (c.title.contains("my searched text"))
        //if (c.title. == "my searched text")
            results.append(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: This it's good solutions, but i need to do a search similar like from SQL, you've already done a search similar: SELECT * FROM test WHERE something LIKE '%my searched text%', how to do in qt "%text%" ?

Comment: I have edited the search but if you are using this for an autocomplete on a UI there is a tool called QCompleter which is smarter.

Comment: @Marco: This [`QCompleter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html) unfortunately looks like it is designed to be used with `QtWidgets`.

Comment: *The UI*? QML is just as much **The UI**, isn't it?

Comment: Well I do not like QML, I still prefer to design UI from code. (but I am old fashioned)